# Mac OSX XAMP for only 1 user

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts, xampp

I am a new Mac convert. My wife and I share our new Macbook Pro, and I would like to hide my own programs from her Launcher list. She has no need to see XAMPP or Photoshop, Atom, CodeKit, or any of my dev and geeky stuff. Just like I don't need to see her games lol.

I successfully moved her games and stuff into her own user's `Applications` folder, hiding them from me :)

On mine, I hid Atom, CodeKit, and some others just fine. Geeky junk hidden from her..

However, my issue is XAMPP. I moved the directory from the global `Applications` directory and put it into my own. When I launched XAMPP, MySQL, ProFTP, and Apache were no longer in the XAMPP services list. So moving it, broke it..

Any easy way to remove XAMPP from my wife's account and still have it work on mine?

Comment: you can try hiding the application by using the *chflags hidden* command - This should hide the application from view, but you are still able to access them if you navigate to them within terminal. I haven't tested this between accounts, but its worth a shot.